# Puppeteer with TypeScript not working with esModuleInterop

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer, tsc

If I'm trying to use puppeteer with TypeScript and esModuleInterop=true set in tsconfig.json I get an error saying

> puppeteer.launch is not a function

if I try to import puppeteer with

```
import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";
```

Now to my question: Is this intended behavior or a bug?

For me, it's not a big deal to just set esModuleInterop to false, but it seems odd

---

Small add-on:

if I manually change `puppeteer.launch()` to `puppeteer.default.launch()` in index.js it works

---

Links:

tsconfig.json: https://pastebin.com/6xvkfJg2

package.json: https://pastebin.com/ViwfMwyQ

index.ts: https://pastebin.com/GtHuiHSJ

index.js: https://pastebin.com/TzeCDiGn

Answer (score 1):

Use `import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'` syntax or get rid of `esModuleInterop` flag.

A long time ago, when the typescript language was developed, the ECMAScript modules specification was still in draft. Moreover, the direction of the typescript as a language was slightly different: a typescript team did not hesitate to add features non-compatible with ES. One of these features is modules syntax.

`import * as smth from 'smth'` is a valid typescript code, but not ECMAScript code.
`import smth from 'smth'` is a valid ECMAScript code but is not valid typescript construction.

Flag `esModuleInterop` literally means "we are going to use ECMAScript imports in our code".
Now, when people have adopted and loved ES modules syntax this flag is arguably the standard.

[A more detailed article](https://itnext.io/great-import-schism-typescript-confusion-around-imports-explained-d512fc6769c2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import { launch } from 'puppeteer';
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
const browser = await launch();
```

Comment: Importing this way was causing error for me, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70257338/8153565