# Puppeteer launcher error results with undefined

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, deployment, puppeteer

After testing my project on windows, i've deployed it to Ubuntu-based VM and that is where the Puppeteer behavior baffles me. I did install all required dependencies, but i have a feeling that my error not necessarily derived by lack of dependencies and more about configuration issue.

Function fignature:

```js
  async initPuppeteerBrowser() {
    if (
      this.puppeteerBrowser === null ||
      (await this.puppeteerBrowser.pages()).length === 0
    ) {
      this.puppeteerBrowser = await launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
    }

    return await this.puppeteerBrowser.newPage();
  }
```

Resulted with:

```
err: {
      "type": "TypeError",
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_launcher')",
      "stack":
          TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_launcher')
              at launch (/root/dev/logoex-server/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Puppeteer.js:125:21)
              at CorporationsScraper.initPuppeteerBrowser (/root/dev/logoex-server/dist/aid/scraper/corporations.scraper.js:33:66)
              at CorporationsScraper.corporationIterator (/root/dev/logoex-server/dist/aid/scraper/corporations.scraper.js:54:37)
              at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    }
```

I don't understand how do i even begin to invastigate this issue

Answer (score 9):

Not sure, if this will help in your situation -
I had Typescript, with compilerOptions `lib: ["es2020"]` and it threw this error. Changing it to `lib: ["es2017"]` solved this issue for me. I am not even sure, why it is affecting it like this. I guess, when you get a function by importing like `import { fn } from "somewhere"` but that function is somehow exported from class instance - it loses it's bound `this`.

Otherwise importing like this works

```
// Works
import Puppeteer, { Browser, PDFOptions } from "puppeteer";
browser = await Puppeteer.launch({});

// Doesn't work
import { launch, Browser, PDFOptions } from "puppeteer";
browser = await launch({});
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I changed my import from `import { launch } from "puppeteer";` to `import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";` and it fixed it. I guess `import Puppeteer from "puppeteer";` also works if you have `esModuleInterop` at `true`.

Answer (score 3):

The fix for me was to switch from using:

```
import { launch } from 'puppeteer';
const browser = await launch(...);
```

```
import Puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
const browser = await Puppeteer.launch(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
async initPuppeteerBrowser() {
    if (
      this.puppeteerBrowser === null ||
      (await this.puppeteerBrowser.pages()).length === 0
    ) {
      this.puppeteerBrowser = await launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
    }

    return this.puppeteerBrowser.newPage();
  }
```

Comment: It didn't work, the problem is at the _launcher

Comment: Did you try to do like this? await launch();, You don't need to set headless as "true", that is true as default.

Answer (score 0):

## My environment

I'm running my Node.js app using commonjs module format.

- `puppeteer@13.5.1`
- `typescript@4.5.4`
- `node@14.18.3`
- My `package.json` appropriately does *not* specify `"module": true`.
- Although I do use ES modules syntax in my TypeScript code, I set `"module": "commonjs"` to transpile down to commonjs.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    // ... other inconsequential options ...
  },
}
```

## Failed approaches

I tested on the official TypeScript playground with my above `tsconfig.json` to analyse what each of these different approaches transpile to.

### Method 1

#### Source

```
import { launch } from 'puppeteer';
launch();
```

#### Output

```
const puppeteer_1 = require("puppeteer");
(0, puppeteer_1.launch)();
```

### Method 2

#### Source

```
import { default as puppeteer } from 'puppeteer';
puppeteer.launch();
```

#### Output

```
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const puppeteer_1 = __importDefault(require("puppeteer"));
puppeteer_1.default.launch();
```

### Method 3

#### Source

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
puppeteer.launch();
```

#### Output

```
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(m, k);
    if (!desc || ("get" in desc ? !m.__esModule : desc.writable || desc.configurable)) {
      desc = { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } };
    }
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, desc);
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __setModuleDefault = (this && this.__setModuleDefault) || (Object.create ? (function(o, v) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, "default", { enumerable: true, value: v });
}) : function(o, v) {
    o["default"] = v;
});
var __importStar = (this && this.__importStar) || function (mod) {
    if (mod && mod.__esModule) return mod;
    var result = {};
    if (mod != null) for (var k in mod) if (k !== "default" && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mod, k)) __createBinding(result, mod, k);
    __setModuleDefault(result, mod);
    return result;
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const puppeteer = __importStar(require("puppeteer"));
puppeteer.launch();
```

## Working approach

... so finally, I tried TypeScript's special [`import = require()`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) format.

#### Source

```
import puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
puppeteer.launch();
```

#### Output

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
puppeteer.launch();
```

So this looks most similar to method 1. I'm not really sure what magic method 1 is performing with its `0` argument, but maybe it's erasing the `this` context or something and that's what's causing the module to be unable to find its `launch` property (which it might reference via `this.launch`)? Just speculation.